# grpc_tools did not create xxx_grpc.py

Tags: python-3.x, grpc-python

I am learning grpc, but encounter an issue.

1. create proto file as showing below (test.proto)
2. run `python3 -m  grpc_tools.protoc -I ./protos --python_out=. ./protos/test.proto`

expect to have two files:
`test_pb2.py` and `test_pb2_grpc.py`

but only have `test_pb2.py`

I am not sure which step I am missing.

```
syntax = "proto3";

service PingPongService{
    rpc ping(Ping) returns (Pong){}
}

message Ping{
    int32 count = 1;
}

message Pong{
    int32 count = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems the following arg needs to be added

```
  --grpc_python_out=.
```